# window.location.href not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login").click(function(){
            var user = $('#userID').val(); 
            var pass = $('#password').val();
            if (user === '' || pass === ''){
                alert("Please Fill Required Fields");
            } 
            else {
                alert (user+" " +pass);
                var x="<?php confirm();?>";
                alert (x);
                window.location.href = 'http://localhost/Annapoorna/Welcome_Page.php';
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my HTML

```
<form class="login-form"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="userID" id="userID"/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"/>
    <button id="login" name="login" value="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

The alerts are coming right but `window.location.href` is not redirecting to the specified page. Why?

Comment: Do you get both alerts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why it doesn't work**

Display the href (URL) of the current page:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Page location is " + window.location.href;
```

Result is:

> Page location is http://www.yoururl.com/yourlocation

---

**To make it work**

To redirect to another page, you can use:

```
window.location="http://www.yoursite.com";
```

---

**expand for working example**

```js
function Redirect() {
  window.location="http://www.yoursite.com";
}
```

```html
    <html>
       <head>
                    
       </head>
       
       <body>
          <p>Click the following button, you will be redirected to home page.</p>
          
          <form>
             <input type="button" value="Redirect Me" onclick="Redirect();" />
          </form>
          
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So why doesn't the .href work? That section of the answer does not explain anything

Comment: @Huangism at the time of writing I must have thought location.href was read only. MDN states it is a synonym, that may have changed I don't know. Both should work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 1):

Add a type to the button:

```
    <button id="login" name="login" type="button">Login</button>
```

`value` attribute doesn't seem to be correct on this HTMLButtonElement.

**Why?**

Seems to me, form getting submitted at same page before navigation.

Comment: @VineetBasantani check browser's console do you get any error?

Comment: @VineetBasantani goodluck with that one. Good to see you got it answered.

Comment: Saved my ass. Thanks.